# Marlin NOZZLE_CLEAN_STROKES half a pattern?

Tags: marlin, cleaning

I have Marlin 2.0.9.2 configured to wipe the nozzle on a brass brush mounted to the side of the bed of my printer. It does 3 zigzag movements. It cleans up the ooze nicely from the nozzle BUT... the pattern ends where it began, so it cleans the ooze and then right at the end of the pattern it picks it back up off the brush. Is there a way to do 2.5 or 3.5 patterns, and avoid this? All the cleaning options (straight, circle, zigzag) seem to be cyclic...